# Use custom regular expression with jquery.formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\d_\d-]*$/
```

Now I want to use it with jquery.formatter:
http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/

I doing something like this:

```
 $('#event_url').formatter
    pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\d_\d-]*$/
    persistent: false
```

Is there any way to use custom regex to work with this plugin?

Comment: Side note: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\d_\d-]*$/` can be replaced with `/^[\w-]*$/`. `\d` doesn't need to be repeated multiple times and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\w` (and this covers `\d`, unless you want numeric numbers that are not `0-9`).

Answer (score 0):

This plugin solves my problem:
https://github.com/akzhan/jquery-keyfilter/blob/master/jquery.keyfilter.js